# With Iron Router, Find() and FindOne()

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I loaded Iron:Router with my Meteor, and now I'm having difficulties loading both all of a collection, and one specific entry.

What I'm trying to do: In the Nav Bar, I want to list all of a user's previous entries.  I got that working great.  It lists each into a drop down, provides a proper link, and loads up only what the user has previous input.  In the body it's suppose to load up specific information for each entry.

Whats not working: It's either not giving me a findOne() where the params._id equal the id in the route, or it's not loading anything.  The location is correct.  It's just not loading the info like it should.

UPDATE: I moved some things around and got the 'name' field to print out, still not able to get it to verify owner just yet.  Console prints out: "Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: currentCharacter is not defined"  Replacing with current code.

What am I doing wrong?  Below is the code:

Route:

```
  this.route('character/:_id', {
    template: 'character',
    subscriptions: function() {
      return Meteor.subscribe("characterlist");
      return Meteor.subscribe("characterlist", this.params._id);
    },
    data: function () {
      var routeid = this.params._id;
      return {
        currentCharacter: CharList.findOne({_id: routeid}),
        characterlist: CharList.find({'owner':Meteor.userId()})
      };
    }
  });
```

Template Helper Class:

```
Template.character.helpers({
    characterlist: function () {
      return CharList.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    },
    currentCharacter: function () {
      return CharList.findOne({'_id':Router.current().params._id});
    },
    isOwner: function () {
      return currentCharacter.owner === Meteor.userId();
    }
  });
```

HTML:

```
<template name='character'>

  <div class="container-body">
    {{#if currentUser}}
    <div class="well">
      {{currentCharacter.name}}
      {{#with currentCharacter}}
      {{#if isOwner}}
      <p>Character: {{name}}</p>
      {{else}}
      <p>You are not approved to make spends for this character.</p>
      {{/if}}
      {{/with}}
    </div>
    {{else}}
    <h4>Please log in.</h4>
    {{/if}}

  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me sigh metaphorically out loud online.  Like usual when I ask for help I find what i did wrong.

It needs to get "this" object and pull the "owner" type out.  Once it has "this.owner" it can verify the user is of course the correct owner.  I was trying to be smart and didn't realize it was asking for the wrong information for four hours!  Code below:

```
isOwner: function () {
  return this.owner === Meteor.userId();
}
```